# No picture preview after taking or selecting picture from gallery in ionic view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have below code in my view:

```
    <div class="ponkey-add-top">
        <button class="button add-picture" ng-click="popover.show($event)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add picture</button><br />
        <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" class="take_picture">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea class="ponkey-add-note-textarea" ng-model="data.text" placeholder="Your note..."></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
```

After selecting a picture from my gallery or taking a picture, the preview isn't shown. This was working on iOS and not on Android. Now it's not working on both devices.

The controller has this:

```
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            $scope.image = imageData;
            $scope.popover.hide();
        });
```

At submit, the image data is sent to the server, so the picture is present.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

[cordova-imagePicker](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/imagePicker/)

> For Multiple Image Selection - implemented for iOS and Android 4.0
>   and above.

To Install Simply Run This Command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-image-picker
```

> Example - Get Full Size Images (all default options):

```
  module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaImagePicker) {

  var options = {
   maximumImagesCount: 10,
   width: 800,
   height: 800,
   quality: 80
  };

  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // error getting photos
    });
});
```

Comment: Well the way I do it works like documented, only the picture is not shown in the view. The example you give, still doesn't tell me how to display it in ionic view

Comment: its simply looping all the image uri from gallery .Now you can set that image uri as image src.

Comment: Aren't we doing that within the function? `$scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;`

Comment: In that case you getting recently captured image.

Comment: And that's what I want. It just doesn't show in the view. In Android I get a broken image icon and in iOS just blank space

Comment: @AlvinBakker 
 I used these commands

`ionic cordova platform remove android` and
`ionic cordova platform add android`

so solve the error of the broken image icon and the plugin image picker functioned correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out what I had to do. The function and the view posted in the question was correct.

But in index.html I have to specify `Content-Security-Policy` a bit more with `img-src 'self' data:` and add below code to apps.js:

```
   .config(function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);
    })
```